# How do I use Combres to embed the actual minified resource instead of a link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combres

I'm writing an MVC view which will be sent as an HTML email. Since many mail clients don't render external CSS stylesheets, I need to include them inline. Since I'm already using [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/) to combine and minify my stylesheets on the main site, I want to use it to insert the styles into my email view.

I could use `Html.CombresLink("siteCss")` to render a `<link>` to the minified stylesheet, but how do I render the *actual CSS inline* instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Combres doesn't support that.  Given the fact that combined sets are usually large, I can't really see the reason why you would inline them.  Externalizing them will use the browser cache efficiently while not doing so, you have to load the content every single time the page is loaded.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I need to inline them because I'm building an HTML email, and many mail clients don't pull in external stylesheets. Thanks for confirming that it isn't supported, however. (It's always cool to have a project's creator pop in to answer your question!)

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the alternate method, `CombresUrl("siteCss")` to get the URL to the combined and minified CSS, then use a `WebClient` to request that URL and get the contents as a string, then include that in the email.

Yes, it adds a bit of overhead for the time taken to make the request, but it should work.